# Can not find out what causes my iOS app crashes in flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I'm using flutter as a tool to create an app for Android and iOS. The Android version is working fine, but the iOS version crashes right after I log in or logout in the app. I'm using Firebase in my app. I'm not sure why the iOS version crashes but I get this message in the Run log.

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39f0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ad79b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39c88 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff258a3d9b -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
    4   Runner                              0x0000000103d42cd7 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util16ObjcThrowHandlerENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 343
    5   Runner                              0x0000000103d42525 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util5ThrowENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__<…>
```

Update:
I tested the app by running it using

```
flutter run --verbose
```

And got this message:

```
localhost Runner[23602]: (Foundation) *** Assertion failure in firebase::firestore::api::DocumentReference::DocumentReference(model::ResourcePath, std::shared_ptr<Firestore>)(),
/-/-/AndroidStudioProjects/qyou/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/api/document_reference.cc:66
[  +77 ms] [DEVICE LOG] 2020-04-26 22:52:09.812988-0400  localhost Runner[23602]: (CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid
document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1'
[        ] [DEVICE LOG] *** First throw call stack:
[        ] [DEVICE LOG] (
[        ] [DEVICE LOG]     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39f0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
[        ] [DEVICE LOG]     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ad79b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
[        ] [DEVICE LOG]     2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39c88 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
[        ] [DEVICE LOG]     3   Foundation                          0x00007fff258a3d9b -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
[        ] [DEVICE LOG]     4   Runner                              0x0000000100edacd7 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util16ObjcThrowHandlerENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 343
[        ] [DEVICE LOG]     5   Runner                              0x0000000100eda525 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util5ThrowENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__<…>
```

Comment: I would make sure you have the plist configuration file Google has given you to use Firebase in your iOS project.

Comment: the plist file is in the ios project. But still I get the issue

Answer (score 1):

I turned out that in one of the functions I pass an empty string as the document uid which caused this exception to be thrown.